# Angular Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] after merging js files to one file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gulp-concat

I have created an angular application and the application is working fine if I am using the controllers.js, routes.js, directives.js etc seperately in index.html. But when I combine the js files into one js file using gulp-concat (In the same order in which I included the files in my HTML) then I am getting the error Angular Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]  I am not sure how to proceed as the error is not very specific

Comment: Is that the full error? Usually it states which controller, service etc it can't inject. Also are you minifying your JavaScript to? If so are you using the array notation?

Comment: it sounds like you aren't declaring your controllers using the minification safe syntax, but without seeing any code it's impossible to know for sure.  if you are using Angular 1.3 or higher, you can use `ng-strict-di` on the same element as your `ng-app` to test for dependency injection issues.

Comment: could you add your gulp code and also your application structure?

Comment: @ste2425 I am not minifying the JS (I was going to but I was stuck before that step) but according to the URL which I was redirected to was telling me that I missed the module, will check the gulp task again

Comment: @gon250 I checked the gulp code and was missing a main file, its working now

Comment: @SaurabhUdaniya If you have fixed it you can post an answer for your own question and accept it. May help others who have a similar issue.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it, after going through the error I found that my gulp task was skipping some js files which were present in the application, I fixed the gulp task and ran it again which fixed the issue. After that I uglified the js files by passing mangle set to false so that the function arguments should stay the same and after that everything ran easily

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Gulp. With CDNs it work just fine but using local .min files I got Error: [$injector:modulerr]

I've solved it by adding the following:

```
.pipe(uglify({ mangle: false })
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by making sure I included all my dependency injections(DI)  properly by supplying them with a name like for example for .config UI Router DI:

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider   . . .
```